# Ruby Branch and Bound Algorithm implementation?

Tags: algorithm, ruby

I am relatively new to Ruby and am trying to get a handle on making my code more Ruby-esque. At the same time I am experimenting with the branch and bound algorithm to solve a problem that I outline in this [blog post](http://www.mikecordell.com/blog/2013/05/05/branch-bound-problem-in-ruby.html). I would also welcome any feedback on the quality of my implementation. The full source code is on my [github here](https://github.com/mcordell/branch_bound_example), but here is the code for the branch bound class:

```
require './widget'
require './requirements'
require 'benchmark'

class BranchBoundSearch
  @best_score = nil
  @best_combos = []

  def initialize(scorer, main_requirement_label, all_possible)
    @scorer = scorer
    @main_requirement_label = main_requirement_label
    @all_possible = all_possible
  end

  # Given a widget_array first calculate it's score, and add it as a branch in the
  # list of branches based on the quality of it's score. Better scores are first.
  # Branches that do not meet the size requirement are not added to the branches
  # array. This effectively kills that branch.
  def add_branch(widget_array, branches)
    score_hash = @scorer.get_score_hash(widget_array)
    score = @scorer.get_total_score(score_hash)
    added = false
    branches_index = 0

    if score_hash[@main_requirement_label] >= 0 
      while not added and branches_index < branches.length do
        if @scorer.get_better_score(score, branches[branches_index][1]) >= 0
            branches.insert(branches_index, [score_hash,score,widget_array])
            added = true
        end
        branches_index += 1
      end

      if not added
        branches.push([score_hash, score,widget_array])
      end
    end
  end

  # Branch and bound recursive search. Provided an in array which represents the
  # node which will be branched off of. Roughly, the function first creates a list
  # of potential branches which are ordered by the quality of their score.
  # Potential branches are then looped through, if a potential branch is viable the
  # function is called again with it as the root node. This continues until
  # exhaustion of all possiblities.

  def branch_and_bound(in_array)
    branches = []
    @all_possible.each do |widget|
      branch_array = in_array + [widget]
      add_branch(branch_array, branches)  
    end

    branches.each do |branch|
      score_hash = branch[0]
      score = branch[1]
      widget_array = branch[2]
      score_comparison = @scorer.get_better_score(score, @best_score)

      if score_comparison == 0 
        @best_combos.push(widget_array)
        continue_branch_investigation = true
      elsif score_comparison == 1
        @best_combos = [widget_array]
        @best_score = score
        continue_branch_investigation = true
      elsif score > 0 
          continue_branch_investigation = true
      end

      if continue_branch_investigation
        branch_and_bound(widget_array)
      end
    end
  end

  def get_best_score()
    return @best_score, @best_combos
  end
end
```

I'm also concerned about this specific code block:

```
best_score_90 = nil
best_set_90 = []
best_score_90_bb = nil
best_set_90_bb = []
best_score_400 = nil
best_set_400 = []
best_score_400_bb = nil
best_set_400_bb = []
time=Benchmark.bm(7) do |x|
  x.report("brute[90]:") do
    scorer = Scorer.new(requirements_90, :size)
    brute = BruteSearch.new(scorer, :size)
    possible_combos = brute.enumerate_possible([], all_widgets.dup)
    best_score_90, best_set_90 = brute.get_best_score
  end

  x.report("brute[400]:") do
    scorer = Scorer.new(requirements_400, :size)
    brute = BruteSearch.new(scorer, :size)
    possible_combos = brute.enumerate_possible([], all_widgets.dup)
    best_score_400, best_set_400 = brute.get_best_score
  end

  x.report("b&b[90]:") do
    scorer = Scorer.new(requirements_90, :size)
    bb = BranchBoundSearch.new(scorer, :size, all_widgets)
    bb.branch_and_bound([])
    best_score_90_bb, best_set_90_bb = bb.get_best_score
  end
  x.report("b&b[400]:") do
    scorer = Scorer.new(requirements_400, :size)
    bb = BranchBoundSearch.new(scorer, :size, all_widgets)
    bb.branch_and_bound([])
    best_score_400_bb, best_set_400_bb = bb.get_best_score
  end
end

puts "Best set [90] brute: " + widget_array_to_s(best_set_90)
puts "Score[90] brute: " + best_score_90.to_s
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: A note from experience: if you ask to review so many LOC, chances are nobody will answer, too much work. Maybe you can reduce it to a method you're specially worried about.

Comment: This is just a style suggestion, but please do use the spacebar a little more. It is more "Ruby'esque" to write `x = y` and `foo(bar, baz)`, instead of `x=y`, `foo(bar,baz)`. Same with commented lines: `# comment` instead of `#comment`. Last tip: Generally speaking, array variables are plural nouns, so `widgets` instead of `widget_array`. This naming scheme is why Ruby's `Array` has a method called `include?`. The line `widgets.include?(x)` makes grammatical sense, while `widget_array.include?(x)` doesn't really.

Comment: Small thing but you don't need to write `return` in `get_best_score`. Result of last evaluation is returned by default in Ruby.

Comment: Is there any case when this will be false (or nil)? `continue_branch_investigation`

Answer (score 1):

One thing that will help a lot is using `attr_accessor`. You can use is so that you don't have so many instance variables littering your methods. You can also initialize `best_score` and `best_combos` and give them default values. (But generally, according to [Sandi Metz](http://cloud.nickcox.me/3Y1R0B343S42), you should try to avoid passing in more than 4 arguments to any method.) Also, avoid `if not`. Opt instead for `unless`.

```
class BranchBoundSearch

  attr_accessor :scorer, :main_requirement_label, :all_possible, :best_score, :best_combos

  def initialize(scorer, main_requirement_label, all_possible, best_score=, best_combos)
    @scorer = scorer
    @main_requirement_label = main_requirement_label
    @all_possible = all_possible
    @best_score = nil
    @best_combos = []
  end
  # That way, you have access to scorer without calling @scorer.
  def add_branch(widget_array, branches)
    score_hash = scorer.get_score_hash(widget_array)
    score      = scorer.get_total_score(score_hash)
  ...
  unless added
    branches.push([score_hash,score,widget_array])
  end
  ...
```

That will get you at least some of the way, but you did post quite a bit of code.

Answer (score 0):

**Replace this**

```
branches.each do |branch|
  score_hash = branch[0]
  score = branch[1]
  widget_array = branch[2]
  ...
```

with

```
branches.each do |score_hash, score, widget_array|
  ...
```

**This one**

```
if score_comparison == 0 
  ...
elsif score_comparison == 1
  ...
elsif score > 0 
  ...
end
```

with

```
case score_comparison
  when 0
    ...
  when 1
    ...
  else
    ...
end
```

**You pass a param but there's no reason for it**

`add_branch(branch_array, branches)`

because you may make `branches` an instance variable `@branches`.